# In Java, does subclassing and overriding the same method cause runtime inefficiency?

Tags: java

I read somewhere, a while ago - and I don't recall where, that subclassing several times and each time overriding the same method, causes a run-time inefficiency.

**For example:**

```
Class A{protected myFunction(){}}

Class B extends A{@Override myFunction(){}}

Class C extends B{@Override myFunction(){}}
```

Is it true that calling `myFunction()` from within Class A is now "slower" ? I remember that the author described the inefficiency due to pointer lookup that had to be done in order to access the correct overriding method.

Comment: I would think it would be more "inefficient" if you had a bunch of subclasses (same branch) but only the top-most parent implemented the method. The late binding would have to traverse the whole hierarchy to find the implementation. In your case, it only needs to look at the instance's type to find an implementation.

Comment: For what version of Java?

Comment: Whoever told you that was full of it.  The JVM doesn't even see the superclass methods, once the class is loaded.  In fact there is **zero performance difference** in calling a method that is in the 27th subclass vs calling one in the 27th superclass -- they're all the same, once the class has been loaded.  (Calling a method on an interface is less efficient, but still the cost is the same regardless of where the interface method is located in the hierarchy.)

Comment: ... and in these days of Hotspot re-compilation, the interface overhead may go away too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain in a bit more detail:

Inside the JVM's private representation for each loaded class is a table of method pointers.  When you compile Class X, the methods xMethod1, xMethod2, xMethod3 are assigned slots in the table -- always in the same order.  Let's say that Object has slots 0-10, so X has slots 11, 12, and 13.

When you the define Class Y as a subclass of X, the private representation for Y's slots 0-13 of it's method table are copied from X's method table.  Then yMethod1, yMethod2, yMethod3 are assigned slots 14, 15, and 16 in the new table.  So one can call a method by index and always get the right version.

Now if Class Y also defines it's own version of xMethod2, the pointer to that version is placed in the method table *of the representation for Y's class* at slot 12, overlaying the method pointer from Class X.

When you create an object instance, a pointer to the class's private representation is placed in the instance header, so, when a method is called, the method table can be consulted and the correct method accessed (with the method table index values effectively having been compiled into the bytecodes).

So the call function is: fetch private representation pointer from object header, fetch table pointer in private representation, index table with literal index, fetch method pointer, transfer control to method.

**Interface methods:**  There are probably several different implementations of the call mechanism for interfaces, but I suspect that most do about what ours did and, instead of indexing the "method table" used for virtual calls, they consult a hashtable.  Rather than searching using the method name, a pre-calculated method identifier is used to search the hashtable and fetch the method pointer, so the mechanism is fast and compact.

Again, the mechanism does not "care" how deeply things are subclassed/subinterfaced.